# An illegal XML character "001A" was found in an SQL/XML expression or function argument sql QUERY

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I am trying to concatenate 1 column data by grouping other columns using `XMLAGG()` but I am facing XML bad data issue .

SQL error:

> An illegal XML character "001A" was found in an SQL/XML expression or function argument

This is my query:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL_ID, VNDR_ID,
CASE WHEN (TEXTPREVIEW > ' ') 
 THEN 
substr(xmlserialize(Xmlagg(Xmltext(Concat(', ',Trim( TEXTPREVIEW)))) as clob), 3) 
END AS Notes
from CONTACT_ETL_NOTE_TABLE
where TEXTPREVIEW <> ''
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL_ID, VNDR_ID,TEXTPREVIEW
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

If the data is less than 32K you would be better using `LISTAGG`

but if all you need is to remove the byte sequence x'001A', then you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` for that (depending on your Db2 version).

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL_ID, VNDR_ID
,   CASE WHEN (TEXTPREVIEW > ' ') 
         THEN substr(xmlserialize(Xmlagg(Xmltext(Concat(', ',Trim(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXTPREVIEW,'\x00\x1A','') )))) as clob), 3) END AS Notes 
from
    CONTACT_ETL_NOTE_TABLE
where
    TEXTPREVIEW <> ''
GROUP BY
    FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL_ID, VNDR_ID,TEXTPREVIEW
```

or as `001A` might be UTF-16, and in UTF-8 you actually have a `UTF-8: 0x1A` then you might just need `REGEXP_REPLACE(TEXTPREVIEW,'x1A','')`. So maybe check what byte(s) you have that are causing the issue.  Note that XML does not allow x00-x1F control characters (although Unicode is fine with them... go figure)